# What does this mean in C# y -= y > 9 ? 9:0;

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

While I´m trying to understand a C# codeblock, I´m asking myself what does this code means:

```
y -= y > 9 ? 9:0;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What aspect of it don't you understand?

Comment: Was reading a codeblock in C#. Wanted to understand it but didn´t know what acutally this was. Until now. Thanks to you all guys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes this bit of code is a bit confusing.

Basically the logic reads like this:

```
if y is greater than 9
    subtract y by 9
otherwise
    subtract y by 0
```

This is also equivalent to the following code:

```
if (y > 9) {
    y = y - 9;
}
else {
    y = y - 0;
}
```

The else case is of course superfluous in this case but I did a literal translation.

For further reading, you can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).  Good luck!

Comment: @user3240743 Good stuff!  Don't forget to mark an answer if you were answered appropriately!

Comment: @phantom You might want to add a link to the ternary operator page on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 2):

if `y > 9` then subtract 9 from `y` else subtract zero (do nothing).

Answer (score 2):

First evaluation:

```
(y > 9)
```

If this is true, the expression is evaluated to 9.

If this is false it is evaluated to 0.

This evaluated result is then subtracted from the current value of y.

Answer (score 1):

It is here as I suppose:

```
if(y>9)
  y=y-9;
else
  y=y-0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes use of the [? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) in C#. The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression and evaluates as :

```
if(y>9)
  y-= 9;
else
 y-= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

- **-=** is a subtraction operator.
  `y -= (expression)` means subtract (expression) from `y` and store that value in `y`
- **? :** is the ternary operator.   It is a way to write an expression that has a conditional value.
  `(expression) ? x : y` means evaluates to `x` if `(expression)` is true, and it evaluates to `y` if `(expression)` is false

Answer (score 0):

```
y -= something;
```

means

```
y = y - something;
```

"?" is a ternary operator. Its syntax is:

```
condition ? true_expression : false_expression
```

So, the equivalent of that line is:

```
if (y > 9)
    y = y - 9;
else
    y = y - 0; // Of course, this wouldn't make sense written like this.
```

A clear and concise version of that line could be:

```
if (y > 9)
    y -= 9;
```